# Update Panel remember scroll position not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scrollbar

This subject has been covered many times however no matter what code I look at none of them work.

I am using Update Panels and when the update panel gets refreshed in async it shoots the scroll bar to the top. I have tried Javascript method with no avail, I have tried adding smartNavigation="True" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True" to the top of page still no avail.

Can someone please give me a working version of keeping the scrollbar position after Async Postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this one, I had to make this being done on client side, so when building the listview I had an id on the table row which called a javascript function that stored the id number in cookie I was looking at, then I used the scrollIntoView() javascript method using the id I was looking at this enabled me to always scroll back to that position after async postback.